# Counting the byte size of a file encoded in ISO 8859-7 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

### Background

I am writing an esoteric language called [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/). It is used on the lovely site [codegolf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). If you don't already know, a lot of challenges are scored in bytes. People have [made](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/) [lots of](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6918/31957) [languages](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/) that utilize either their own encoding or a pre-existing encoding.

On the interpreter for my language, I have a byte counter. As you might expect, it counts the number of bytes in the code. Until now, I've been using a UTF-8 en/decoder (`utf8.js`). I am now using the ISO 8859-7 encoding, which has Greek characters. Nor does the text upload actually work. I need to count the actually bytes contained within an uploaded file. Also, is there a way to read the contents of said encoded file?

### Question

Given a file encoded in ISO 8859-7 obtained from an `<input>` element on the page, is there any way to obtain the number of bytes contained in that file? And, given "plaintext" (i.e. text put directly into a `<textarea>`), how might I count the bytes in that as if it was encoded in ISO 8859-7?

### What I've tried

The input element is called `isogreek`. The file resides in the `<input>` element. The content is `ΦX族`, a Greek character, a latin character (each of which should be a byte) and a Chinese character, which should be more than one byte (?).

```
isogreek.files[0].size;      // is 3; should be more.

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(isogreek.files[0]);      // corrupts the string to `ÖX?`
reader.readAsText(isogreek.files[0]);              // �X?
reader.readAsText(isogreek.files[0],"ISO 8859-7"); // �X?
```

Comment: If this is a file you receive serverside, why not just look at the size of the file?

Comment: @pvg It's all clientside. I'm running it on GitHub.io

Comment: How is the file actually encoded? How do you get a chinese char into an 8-bit, single char encoding? Something here doesn't make sense.

Comment: @pvg I saved that text as in a ISO-8859-7 encoded file. It probably was dropped, or something. The point being, that character can appear in plaintext that needs to be counted as if it were encoded in 8859-7.

Comment: Right but 族 has no meaningful 8859-7 encoding. And since it's a 1-char, 1-byte encoding, as far as i can tell, string or file length should equal char length in that encoding.

Comment: @pvg If that is the case, then it is answer-worthy.

Comment: Well... take a loot at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7, it says "_8-bit single-byte coded graphic character sets_". It's an encoding in which every character is represented by a single byte. And it only does latin and some greek. So in the case of file, that's the answer. In the case of textarea, I don't think there's a particularly meaningful answer since you can type characters that can't be encoded in that encoding at all.

Comment: As pvg has said, the string is corrupted because the Chinese character isn't a part of the ISO-8859-7 charset, which is *exactly 256 unique chars*. If you want to include arbitrary Unicode characters in a program, you will either need to A) count the bytes of that program in i.e. UTF-8 or UTF-16, or B) create your own, custom variant of ISO-8859-7 that uses a specific (maybe unprintable) byte (or a few) to signify that the next 2/3/4 bytes belong to a Unicode char. (If you'd like, I'll expand this comment into an answer later.)

Comment: @ETHproductions An answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not link in the meta post about languages made by PPCG users in your link to languages made by users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Extended from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779256/counting-the-byte-size-of-a-file-encoded-in-iso-8859-7-in-javascript#comment57332216_34779256).</sub>

As @pvg mentioned in the comments, the string resulting from `readAsBinaryString` would be correct, but is corrupted for two reasons:

A. The result is encoded in ISO-8859-**1**. You can use a function to fix this:

```
function convertFrom1to7(text) {
  // charset is the set of chars in the ISO-8859-7 encoding from 0xA0 and up, encoded with this format:
  // - If the character is in the same position as in ISO-8859-1/Unicode, use a "!".
  // - If the character is a Greek char with 720 subtracted from its char code, use a ".".
  // - Otherwise, use \uXXXX format.
  var charset = "!\u2018\u2019!\u20AC\u20AF!!!!.!!!!\u2015!!!!...!...!.!....................!............................................!";
  var newtext = "", newchar = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var char = text[i];
    newchar = char;
    if (char.charCodeAt(0) >= 160) {
      newchar = charset[char.charCodeAt(0) - 160];
      if (newchar === "!") newchar = char;
      if (newchar === ".") newchar = String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 720);
    }
    newtext += newchar;
  }
  return newtext;
}
```

B. The Chinese character isn't a part of the [ISO-8859-7 charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7#Codepage_layout) (because the charset supports up to 256 unique chars, as the table shows). If you want to include arbitrary Unicode characters in a program, you will probably need to do one of these two things:

1. Count the bytes of that program in i.e. UTF-8 or UTF-16. This can be done pretty easily with the library you linked. However, if you want this to be done automatically, you'll need a function that checks if the content of the textarea is a valid ISO-8859-7 file, like this:

```
function isValidISO_8859_7(text) {
  var charset = /[\u0000-\u00A0\u2018\u2019\u00A3\u20AC\u20AF\u00A6-\u00A9\u037A\u00AB-\u00AD\u2015\u00B0-\u00B3\u0384-\u0386\u00B7\u0388-\u038A\u00BB\u038C\u00BD\u038E-\u03CE]/;
  var valid = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    valid = valid && charset.test(text[i]);
  }
  return valid;
}
```

2. Create your own, custom variant of ISO-8859-7 that uses a specific byte (or more than one) to signify that the next 2 or 3 bytes belong to a single Unicode char. This can be pretty much as simple or complex as you like, from one char signifying a 2-byte char and one signifying a 3-byter to everything between `80` and `9F` setting up for the next few. Here's a basic example that uses `80` as the 2-byter and `81` as the 3-byter (assumes the text is encoded in ISO-8859-1):

```
function reUnicode(text) {
  var newtext = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text.charCodeAt(i) === 0x80) {
      newtext += String.fromCharCode((text.charCodeAt(++i) << 8) + text.charCodeAt(++i));
    } else if (text.charCodeAt(i) === 0x81) {
      var charcode = (text.charCodeAt(++i) << 16) + (text.charCodeAt(++i) << 8) + text.charCodeAt(++i) - 65536;
      newtext += String.fromCharCode(0xD800 + (charcode >> 10), 0xDC00 + (charcode & 1023)); // Convert into a UTF-16 surrogate pair
    } else {
      newtext += convertFrom1to7(text[i]);
    }
  }
  return newtext;
}
```

I can go into either method in more detail if you desire.

Answer (score 2):

The three characters you gave as an example are decoded in 6 bytes `a6 ce e6 58 8f 97` (0x58 = X). Also: JavaScript works with utf16 which results in some funny things like  `("abc".length === "ΦX族".length)` being true.

You most probably need to go to the full length and check every single character for its length by its code-value. You may also need to check two characters in some cases (utf-32 to utf-16). A BOM needs to be placed and checked, too, if necessary (always necessary if you work with files of unknown sources).

**EDIT:** added on request:

The encodings of the characters in JavaScript is always in utf-16, a two byte representation of the character. That was all well and nice until they suddenly (ha!) found out that two bytes are not really sufficient for all of the alphabets of the world, so the expanded the Unicode range to four bytes: utf-32.

Well, the Unicode consortium did so but the ECMA committee did not.

It cannot be said that hell broke loose but it is quite close in some circumstances, and one of those is your case because you want to mix one-byte encodings with multiple-byte encodings, different ones even.

One byte fits well in two bytes but three or more bytes do not fit well in two bytes, so the so called [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF) were invented. These surrogates are also the reason why it is not so simple to [reverse a string](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/esrever) in JavaScript.

As I said: a large can of worms.

Comment: Explain it to me like I'm a layman. I know pretty much nothing about character encodings.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I'm pretty sure you don't because you wouldn't have started such thing in the first place if you would have known ;-) Give me a couple of minutes to edit (I'm not the fastest typist)

Comment: On your own time! And, yeah, "pretty much" is a relative term :P

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right track since the poster is after 'length in 8859-7', so UTF-anything, BOMS, etc aren't really relevant. `"abc".length === "ΦX族".length` is actually exactly what you want, in that case.

Comment: @pvg (I really should reload the page before hitting enter, sorry.) I hope you're right, would save the OP a lot of headaches.

Comment: Yeah I _think_ it's really about cramming everything into an 8 bit latin/greek encoding, presumably so you can use greek letters for more crap in the maximally-terse code golf language while keeping actual 'file' length to a minimum.